# EF Saving Instances on Wrong Order

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following example classes:

```
public class A {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class AConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<A> {
    public AConfigurations() {
         HasOptional(x=> x.B)
             .WithRequired();
    }
}
```

When I am adding a new instance of A and B like the following:

```
var a = new A() {
    B = new B() {
        SomeProperty = "Some Value"
    }
};
context.As.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();
```

With that model in mind, migration creates a table for A with a Guid PK, and a table for B. B have its PK marked as a FK to A, which is correct for my needs.

The problem is: when it hits SaveChanges, EF tries to insert B before inserting A, which creates a FK exception on database.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in EF 6?

Answer (score 0):

If you use EF Code First (well you use Fluent api at least), you could add the attribute shown below to your primary keys first:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

You are using object initializers here, but you are not setting Id to a specific Guid value. They might get sent in to the database the Guid.Empty value for example.

Saving an object graph for the scenario of adding it to the database is supported in EF, you can study this example. Note that ids here are integers, not Guids.

[Code Sample EF Saving related data](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Saving/Saving/RelatedData/Sample.cs)

So first I would try adding the DatabaseGenerated option to you ids, which can also be set up using the Fluent API.

Comment: All Guid properties are set by conventions. I also thought about zero-guid values, but normal random guids are shown in logs. And I can see the dependant object being inserted before the main object.

Comment: Perhaps it is because you are mixing the () and  { object intializer here. Try to avoid using the () parentheses and only object initializer. Like: 
var a = new A {
    B = new B {
        SomeProperty = "Some Value"
    }
};
context.As.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();